# How to get the process ID by Excel object in C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vsto

I have an object of Excel, `sheet.Excel.Application eApp`.

How do I get the process ID of this Excel application and how do I kill that process?

Comment: Obligatory Old New Thing link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/11/18/10238335.aspx

Comment: You should be able to call `ExcelApp.Quit()`. See [this link](http://www.craigmurphy.com/blog/?p=82)

Comment: Calling Quit() on the application object often does not work, so this is not a very good answer.  There is a perfectly good reason for wanting the process id so as to be able to kill Excel reliably when it goes out to lunch.

Answer (score 2):

```
var app = new ApplicationClass();

...

app.Quit();
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.quit.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the normal `Quit` method of the `ApplicationClass` class, you can try the below, though it is subject to some, but not all, of the pitfalls mentioned in the [link](http://www.craigmurphy.com/blog/?p=82) @Mark Pim suggested.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process[] myProcesses;
// Returns array containing all instances of Excel.
myProcesses = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("Excel");
foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process myProcess in myProcesses)
{
    if (myProcess.MainWindowTitle == Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.Caption)
    {
        myProcess.Kill();
    }
}
```